Compatibility condition with the adjunct pair of derived functors
$\def\C{\mathsf{C}}
\def\D{\mathsf{D}}
\def\hoc{\mathsf{HoC}}
\def\hod{\mathsf{HoD}}
\def\L{\mathbf{L}}
\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$I'm a little confused by [R, Remark 6.4.14]. Before stating the remark, I'll introduce the jargon: A homotopical category is a category equipped with a class of morphisms (named, ‘the weak equivalences’) that satisfy the 2-out-of-6 property [R, Definitions 6.4.1, 6.4.3]. Given a homotopical category $\C$, its homotopy category, $\hoc$ is defined to be the strict localization of $\C$ with respect the weak equivalences (that is, there is a functor $\C\to\hoc$ which is initial in the category of functors under $\C$ that send all weak equivalences to isomorphisms) [R, Definition 6.4.4]. Given a functor $F:\C\to\D$ between homotopical categories, if the right Kan extension of $\C\xrightarrow{F}\D\to\hod$ along $\C\to\hoc$ exists, we denote it by $\L F$ and call it the total left derived functor of $F$ (dually, one defines the total right derived functor $\R G$ of $G:\D\to \C$) [R, Definition 6.4.8].

[R, Proposition 6.4.13]. Suppose $F\dashv G$ is an adjunction between homotopical categories and
suppose also that $F$ has a total left derived functor $\L F$, $G$ has a total right derived functor $\R G$, and both derived functors are absolute Kan extensions. Then the total derived functors form an adjunction $\L F \dashv \R G$ between the homotopy categories.

(Recall that a Kan extension is said to be absolute whenever it is preserved by any functor departing from the target of the extension, in the sense of [R, Definition 6.3.1].)
Here's where I have the issue:

[R, Remark 6.4.14]. If $F\dashv G$ is an adjunction satisfying the hypotheses of Proposition 6.4.13, then the adjunction

between the total derived functors is the unique adjunction compatible with the localization functors $\gamma:\C\to\hoc$ and $\delta:\D\to\hod$ in the sense that the diagram
$$
\label{diag}\tag{1}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    \D(Fc,d)@>\cong >>\C(c,Gd)\\
    @V\delta VV@VV\gamma V\\
    \hod(Fc,d)@.\hoc(c,Gd)\\
    @V Fq^*VV@VV Gr_*V\\
    \hod(\L Fc,d)@>\smash\cong >>\hoc(c,\R Gd)
\end{CD}
$$
commutes for each pair $c\in\C$, $d\in\D$.

My only question is: why is this true? Moreover, what are $Fq$ and $Gr$ in the last diagram? The remark states we are operating under the hypotheses of Proposition 6.4.13. Nonetheless, the choice of the notation $q$ and $r$ makes it seem we need the hypotheses of [R, Proposition 6.4.11], which require the existence of a so-called left deformation $q$ and right deformation $r$ [R, Definition 6.4.10].

References
[R] E. Riehl, Category Theory in Context

$\def\C{\mathsf{C}}
\def\D{\mathsf{D}}
\def\hoc{\mathsf{HoC}}
\def\hod{\mathsf{HoD}}
\def\L{\mathbf{L}}
\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$We don't need the hypotheses of [R, Proposition 6.4.11], only those of [R, Proposition 6.4.13] suffice.
Before stating [R, Proposition 6.4.11], Riehl credits the result to [M]. It is in the statement of [M, theorem] where we find what we need to deduce commutativity of \eqref{diag}. In [M, theorem] it is said that the the (co)unit morphisms $:\L F\cdot \R G\to 1_\hod$ and $:1_\hoc\to\R G\cdot \L F$ may be picked such that the following squares commute:
$$
\label{squares}\tag{$*$}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\L F\cdot \delta\cdot G@>\alpha G>> \gamma\cdot F\cdot G\\
@V(\L F)\beta VV@VV\gamma\varepsilon V\\
\L F\cdot\R G\cdot \gamma@>\smash{\gamma}>>\gamma
\end{CD}\qquad\qquad
\begin{CD}
\R G\cdot \gamma\cdot F@<\beta F<< \delta\cdot G\cdot F\\
@A(\R G)\alpha AA@AA \delta\eta A\\
\R G\cdot \L F\delta@<\smash{\delta}<< \delta
\end{CD}
$$
where $\alpha:\L F\cdot\delta\to \gamma\cdot F$ and $\beta:\delta\cdot G\to\R G\cdot\gamma$ are the comparison transformations. But this means exactly that the data $(F,G,\L F,\R G,\alpha,\beta)$ defines a lax morphism of adjunctions [ref]. Thus, as it is explained in the linked answer, the diagram
$$
\label{diag'}\tag{1'}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    \D(Fc,d)@>\cong >>\C(c,Gd)\\
    @V\delta VV@VV\gamma V\\
    \hod(Fc,d)@.\hoc(c,Gd)\\
    @V \alpha_c^*VV@VV \beta_{d,*}V\\
    \hod(\L Fc,d)@>\smash\cong >>\hoc(c,\R Gd)
\end{CD}
$$
commutes. Lastly, uniqueness as asserted in [R, Remark 6.4.14] comes from the fact that if we have some adjunction $\L F\dashv \R G$ such that \eqref{diag'} commutes, then by [ref] the squares \eqref{squares} commute. But such $$, $$ are unique, as it is shown in the proof of [M, theorem].

References
[R] E. Riehl, Category Theory in Context
[M] G. Maltsiniotis. Le théorème de Quillen, d’adjonction des foncteurs dérivés, revisité. C. R. Math.
Acad. Sci. Paris, 344(9):549–552, 2007
